# I was trying to get rid of an error "Failed to load extention". Tried to solve it but now getting WebDriverException. How to resolve it?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class SetChromeOptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe\\");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
        options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
        options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("disable-extensions");

        Constants.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Constants.driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        Constants.driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I tried to fix the error I was as "Failed to load Extention". But now I am getting this error of WebDriverException. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Please provide stacktrace where exactly you are getting this exception. Also what is the use of Constants class define static WebDriver instance?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'GOVIND-PC', ip: 'xxxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:

Comment: Provide details on version of selenium, chrome driver and browser

Comment: browser 80.0.3987.149

Comment: selenium 3.141.59

Comment: chromedriver.exe 80.0.3987.106